# Mercurial error while connectin on Bitbucket after updating TLS

Tags: ssl, mercurial

So bitbucket upgade his TLS version and now I have problem pulling from bitbucket repos. I have only one server affected and I can't figure out what is wrong.
The error is
 `[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:581)`

I have Debian 8.7 and Mercurial 3.1.2. I tried to remove/purge the package and reinstall it, no way. I did update some tls libraries too.
I can't upggrade the distro cause I need these exact versions of php and mysql.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue? If so, can you update us? I've been pulling my hair for the past few days to no avail.

Comment: No, I can't get this thing working...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477683/mercurial-https-clone-abort-error-wrong-version-number
This worked man!